# PowerShell dynamic menu from xml

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm drawing a blank here and I'm sure the answer is right in front of me. I'm trying to build a dynamic menu to launch small apps in a WinPE image. I'm using an XML file for the data (it seemed the most appropriate)

Now my xml file looks like this

```
<Programs>
    <!-- Programs -->
    <Program Name="7-Zip" Path="\7-Zip\7zFM.exe" Type="Addin"/>
    <Program Name="HwMonitor" Path="\HwMonitor\HwMonitor.exe" Type="Addin"/>
    <!-- HDTools -->
    <Program Name="Defraggler" Path="\Defraggler64\Defraggler64.exe" Type="Hdtools"/>
</Programs>
```

where I'm running into a problem, is the function I wrote to take a `$Type` parameter so I can filter based on the type. The filter itself works fine, it's the part just below for building the menu....it only works if there's more than one item matching that criteria.

```
Function Select-Program($Type)
{
    clear; MenuHeader
    Write-Host " ----------------------------------------------------------------------- "

    $List = $null # set the list to null, for some reason there was duplication when re-entering the menu

    try
    {
        $AddinPath = switch([System.IntPtr]::Size)
        {
            8 {Join-Path (Get-PEDrive).DriveLetter "Programs64"}
            4 {Join-Path (Get-PEDrive).DriveLetter "Programs"}
        }

        $ListFile = Join-Path $AddinPath "Programs.xml"

        [xml]$Programs = Get-Content $ListFile
        Write-Host " "
        $List = $Programs.DocumentElement.Program | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq $Type}

    }
    catch [exception]
    {
    $_.Exception
    }

    # if there's no items in the list, then write a message
    if ($List.Count -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Host "  No Programs Found" -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host " "
    }

    $menu = @{}

    # build menu item list dynamically from the imported data

    for ($i=1;$i -le $List.count; $i++) 
    {
        Write-Host "  $i. $($List[$i-1].Name)" -foregroundcolor White
        $menu.Add($i,($List[$i-1].Name))
    }

    # add one last item to return to main menu
    Write-Host "  $i. Return to main menu" -foregroundcolor White
    $menu.Add($i,"return")

    #prompt for selection
    Write-Host " "
    [int]$ans = Read-Host ' Enter selection'
    $selection = $menu.Item($ans)

    if ($selection -eq "return")
    {
        MainMenu
    }

    # launch the selected application
    $Launch = Join-Path $AddinPath ($List | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $selection}).Path
    Start-Process $Launch

    Select-Program -Type $Type # reload the program menu
}
```

If I run "Select-Program -Type Addin" with the above XML, I get a menu with 2 items, plus the return to main menu. However, if I run "Select-Program -Type Hdtools" I get nothing because there's only one item with this type in the XML file.

I tried this morning with a CSV file and I get the same thing, so I don't think it has anything to do with where the data is coming from or what format I pull it from.

What am I missing here? I tohught the less than operator was messing me up so I tried less than or equal but that bombed on me too and leaves me scratching my head at the moment

Comment: cast `$list` as an array and see if it works.....`$List = @($Programs.DocumentElement.Program | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq $Type})

Comment: I posted an answer that veers away from your central question because I think it might be a better approach in the long run. But as to why you're having the problem you are, it would help to see the error messages you're getting.

Comment: well that's the problem, I don't get an error message. If there's only one item in the XML file, I get nothing. If I add a second item, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that PowerShell handles the array differently when there's only a single item. I experienced the same behavior importing from CSV. This appears to result specifically from piping the data through the Where-Object cmdlet

When only one item was pulled from the XML $List variable being piped through Where-Object, $List[0].Name returned a blank string, where $List.Name returned the desired value.

The solution was to change this

```
$menu = @{}
for ($i=1;$i -lt $List.count; $i++)
{
    Write-Host "  $i. $($List[$i-1].Name)" -foregroundcolor White
    $menu.Add($i,($List[$i-1].Name))
}
```

To this

```
$menu = @{}
for ($i=1;$i -le $List.Name.count; $i++) 
{
    $DisplayName = switch([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($List[$i-1].Name))
    {
        $true {$List.Name}
        $false {$List[$i-1].Name}
    }

    Write-Host ([string]::Format("  {0}. {1}", $i, $DisplayName)) -foregroundcolor White
    $menu.Add($i,($DisplayName))
}
```

The main items of focus are the following

-change $List.count to $List.Name.count as $List.Count returned a null or empty value when only was item was in the XML data

-change -lt (less than) to -le (less or equal) because with only one item and the $i value starting at one a less than would never meet the criteria

-added a switch variable to check if $List[$i-1].Name returned a null as it did with only a single item. in this case, use $List.Name

-used string.Format method for the output line, not necessary, but I find it to be a more predictable method of joining strings in some cases

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest a different approach that I think will simplify the whole process.

First, generate objects that represent what you're storing in XML, then export them as CliXML or JSON:

```
$objects = @()
$objects += [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = "7-Zip"
    Path = "\7-Zip\7zFM.exe"
    Type = "Addin"
}
$objects += [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = "Defraggler"
    Path ="\Defraggler64\Defraggler64.exe"
    Type = "Hdtools"
}
# etc.
$objects | Export-CliXml -Path C:\my.xml
$objects | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path C:\my.json
```

Now, when you want to bring them back in:

```
# from xml
$List = Import-CliXml -Path C:\my.xml

# or from JSON
$List = Get-Content -Path C:\my.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$List = $List | Where-Object { $_.Type -eq $Type } 

$menu = @{}
for ($i=1;$i -le $List.count; $i++)
{
    Write-Host "  $i. $($List[$i-1].Name)" -foregroundcolor White
    $menu.Add($i,($List[$i-1].Name))
}
```

I think this simplifies the process of exporting and importing objects in a consistent way. The array should be serialized as part of the export process and deserialized as part of the import, so you won't have to worry about a method or cmdlet returning a single object.